# Quick release connectors - 2 poles, max 1.5kW 12V DC?

Tags: connector, dc, 12v

What quick release connectors are good for connecting 2 pairs of wires?

- 2 poles
- Max 1.5kW
- 12V
- DC?

  (optional)
- Splashproof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Anderson Power](http://www.andersonpower.com/products/) products are most commonly used in this sort of application.

Comment: Yup, common for UPSes and mobile homes. The connectors look different for different voltages to lessen the probability of connecting them incorrectly.

Comment: +1 for Andersen, widely used in industry. Waterproof is a difficult one to quantify - are you talking "doesn't mind rain" or "must operate outside a submarine"? Usually, heat-shrink & vaseline are adequate protection for 12v stuff.

Comment: it's splashproof. very grateful for refering to Anderson connector, but the only anderson thing I find in Lithuania is 30A. I need at least 75A (normal operation - up to 800-900W)

Comment: @sharas: There's no way I could know that you're in Lithuania if you don't fill in your profile.

Comment: ok :D, filled it up

Comment: Also, parts are available to buy online from abroad.

Answer (score 1):

Anderson is absolutely the first choice for affordable high current low voltage connectors, though I don't believe they offer anything even remotely sealed.  Another option is [Delphi Power Pack](http://delphi.com/connectors/assets/product_profile/Delphi%20Power%20Pack%20Connection%20Systems_data_sheet.pdf) connectors.  In general, you'd need crimp tooling, though they can be assembled with 'affordable' crimp tools in low volumes.  Current to 250A.

I have no idea about distributors in Lithuania; sorry.

[image]

Comment: _Anderson is absolutely the first choice for affordable high current low voltage connectors_ - thanks for that