# How to choose a replacement DC power connector

Tags: power-supply, components, specifications

I am making a replacement logic board for my 3D printer, since the original board kersploded and the manufacturer won't replace it as the printer model is 3 years old (...).  The original power supply brick is fine, though, so I want to reuse it, but it has a slightly unusual connector for which I haven't been able to find a suitable female part.

The power supply is a Meanwell GS220A24-R7B, supplying up to 9.2A at 24V, and it has a DIN-style connector that looks like this:[image]
Looking at the bottom-left view, the two left-hand pins are ground, and the two right-hand pins are +24VDC.  I'm not sure whether the sleeve is connected to ground.

[This previous answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55989/quick-release-connectors-2-poles-max-1-5kw-12v-dc/56014#56014) seems good, but it would be even better if I could just use a barrel connector from my local Radio Shack equivalent, and I'd prefer not to have to buy a new crimp tool.  More importantly, I don't know if there are any considerations in replacing the original four-pin connector with two pins.  Might the two circuits be connected to separate transformer windings or something?  Will it matter if I tie the two 24V lines together?

Basically I'm wary because there must be some reason the manufacturer chose this connector but I have no idea what it was.

Comment: The [data sheet](http://www.meanwell.com/search/gs220/gs220-spec.pdf) shows the output connector's manufacturer, part number, and pinouts.

Comment: Yes (and the pinout is also labeled on the brick itself), but I haven't been able to buy the appropriate female connector.  Or desolder it from the original board, despite trying very hard...

Comment: The connector is available from [Mouser.](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kycon/KPJX-4S-S/?qs=0QDpPFt3C4bj8uE5yBzCJQ%3D%3D) The desoldering problem probably needs to be posted as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be, that the manufacturer chose the power brick first because its rated power is quite high. And that was the connector they ended up with.

If you still have the damaged logic board, you might want to find out, if the two 24V lines are tied together on the board or if they were used separately. They could be two separate power rails, but my guess is that they used this to reduce the current per contact, as contacts for 9.2A is quite the requirement in a compact space.

I'd use the Molex 8981 series, the ones used on 3.5" HDDs, they are rated for a current of 6.5A per contact, have 4 contacts and are readily available.

Comment: That's a good point! I don't know why I didn't think to look at the original board, and it does indeed seem to tie the two lines together, so I guess that's my answer.  I've had QA problems with my home-crimped Molex connectors in the past, so I'll probably go with something more idiot-proof, but knowing I can use a 2-pin connector gives me plenty of options.